# Which consumes more memory boolean or integer in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

Hi I have an Application where we send the alarm status in the form of integer which can be either 1 or 0. I am using Mongodb to store the alarm status. Mongodb uses a type called integer which can store a 32 bit or 64 bit integer values. It also has a datatype called boolean which stores either a True or False value.I have 2,00,000 records with me with the alarm status of 2,00,000 different devices. My question is how does mongo store a Boolean values in it(basically the internal mechanism)?Also which consumes lesser memory in the mongodb database (boolean or integer)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MongoDB the size of boolean is 2 bytes whereas you can either choose the 32-bit integer data type or 64 bit (4bytes or 8 bytes).

You can check out the whole list of data types here : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/

Comment: According to the BSON specification, a boolean is two bytes. http://bsonspec.org/spec.html

Answer (score 6):

When you are interested in low level application details of mongodb, I would always recommend the [BSON specification](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html), as your reference point.

A boolean is two bytes (one for the type information 'boolean' and one for the value `0x00 for false` and `0x01 for true`. 
A 32-bit integer takes up 5 bytes and a 64-bit integer 9 bytes, where the first byte is for type and the rest for the information.

The performance is unlikely to change if you change the type, since once CPU comparison is very little to do in the overall query.

Comment: I went through the documents and couldn't find the specific place where it is mentioned that one byte is allocated for type in boolean. can you help with this.

Answer (score -1):

You won't like the answer, but it doesn't matter. If your property is boolean in nature use `boolean` regardless the internal representation unless you hit some serious performance problems which require optimization.

Internally I believe Mongo will store the boolean as byte or integer.

Comment: While I agree in practice, this doesn't answer the question. This Q&A is the top search result for "mongodb boolean type disk usage" so there is value for others looking for reference. I think a good answer would touch on both the real answer and practical performance benefits, like user3735005 did.